# Angular 6 Yelp Fusion API GET Request

Tags: angular, api, http, get, yelp

So I am currently learning how to make API requests and Angular 6 and I got my HTTP Get request to the Yelp Fusion Api to work but I don't quite understand one line where I copied from a similar example online to work.

```
private configUrl: string = "https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=boston&term=steak";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

sendHttpRequest() {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer MyApiKey");
  return this.http.get<JSON>(this.configUrl, {
    headers
  });
}
```

If I remove the "https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/" in front of the yelp GET URL, it doesn't work and I get this error in the console. Why is this? Sorry, I am new to this.

```
OPTIONS https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=boston&term=steak 403 ()
Failed to load https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=boston&term=steak: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical CORS Issue that you generally get. CORS is a **browser-based** policy that doesn't allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. To allow it:

1. The requesting Domain should either be white-listed on the API end.
2. Or the requested API should be hit via a proxy server.
3. Or there are several other ways this can be dealt with which is outside the scope of this answer.

The previous segment of the URL(`https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/`) as it seems is doing just that. It's basically acting as a proxy in between your Angular App and the Yelp API(**Case 2**).

Since CORS is a Browser Based policy, and you're hitting the YELP API via `corsanywhere` which is acting as a proxy, you're not getting the CORS issue.